# How does an on hold question affect reputation?

Tags: discussion, reputation, on-hold

If I asked a question and someone vote for `on hold`, how does this affect my reputation? I have searched for quit a while. But I still cannot find a clear answer.

Comment: @Makoto yeah, I have found link too. Thanks. But I think they should add this to their answer . Because after I read that question carefully, I am still confused about how on hold question affect reputation. I am very careful to follow every rule here. But for a newbie, I am still a little confused.

Comment: I know how downvote and upvote affect reputations because that link make it clear. Anyway , thank you a lot.

Comment: @Makoto Do you want to go ahead and put what you've said as an answer?

Comment: Yeah, I think I'll do that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Putting a question on hold, or a question eventually becoming closed, doesn't directly affect your reputation.

The only things that will affect your reputation [are direct interactions with the user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work); a part listing would be:

- Voting, up or down
- Bounties, either awarded or offered
- Serial voting
- Too many spam flags

It might *seem* like a question on hold is affecting reputation, but that may be the side effect of other users downvoting the question, in which case, it's strictly the downvotes causing the person to lose reputation.

Comment: A thing that might be useful to point out though is that deletions *do* affect reputation (but gaming this to avoid rep loss from bad questions/answers is a surefire way to get you closer to a ban)

Comment: @DennisMeng Sorry I don't get your point.I know delete a bad question may help to gain the reputation. But is deleting a bad question good or bad?

Comment: @einverne If you can make any effort to save a question without deleting, to do. Only delete if it's completely unsalvageable and unlikely to help anyone later. If that happens, please *use that as a lesson* to help learn how to write a good question. People with a history of posting bad questions (deleted or not) can be subjected to a question ban.

Comment: @DennisMeng Thank you for your advice.